# External scripts in tag manager within a single page app built with React aren't working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-tag-manager

We have a single page app built with react that also uses GTM to load external scripts like Google Analytics 4, Microsoft Clarity, etc. For some reason none of the external scripts are functioning unless using tag assistant or preview mode in GTM.

The 3 external scripts we have are:
-Pardot's Tracking Script
-Zoominfo's Tracking Script
-Microsoft Clarity's Tracking Script

All three of these are in Custom HTML GTM tags triggered by the "All Pages" trigger.

I do not see these scripts loading in DevTools and no activity is logged in each of these services unless in GTM preview mode.

I've also tried loading these scripts via the following triggers with no change:
-Window Loaded
-Dom Ready

I know that GTM is loading correctly because we have several GA4 event tags that fire on several different triggers. The only issue seems to be loading external scripts.

Could this be something related to React? My searches don't return anything relevant.